# How do you share an instance of an ADBannerView with 2 UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, iad

At https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2286/_index.html, Apple recommends that applications only share an instance of an ADBannerView. Now I have two UIViewControllers so I have the following code set up:

Singleton.h

```
ADBannerView *iadBanner;
```

Singleton.m

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"Bank loaded iAd!");
    [ViewController1 showiAd:(iadBanner)];
    [ViewController2 showiAd:(iadBanner)];
}
```

ViewController1.h

```
ADBannerView *iadBanner;
```

ViewController1.m

```
- (void)showiAd:(ADBannerView *)ad {
    NSLog(@"VC iAd Shown!");
    iadBanner = ad;
    [iadBanner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:iadBanner];
}
```

ViewController2.h/ViewController2.m same as ViewController1.h/.m

Instead of both UIViewControllers having the ad displayed however, only the second one does. Now I'm guessing that's because they're both referring to the same instance instead of creating another instance of the iadbanner passed from the Singleton class. Does anybody know how to fix this? :)

Comment: I would stick to Apples recommendation and only display one. If you still want to display two AdBanners you should set up each individually in both the view controllers views. That way you could display in both.

Comment: I think you missed my question. I was asking how to share one instance and have two separate uiviewcontrollers display it but thanks anyway :)